# How to judge whether the compound series is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Note:** The following questions are from the 4th question of the [2009 Chinese Graduate Mathematical Entrance Examination](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/305b69ee4afe04a1b071de1f.html) (first set):

There are two series  $\left\{a_{n}\right\}$,$\left\{b_{n}\right\}$. If $ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=0$, which of the following conclusions is correct:

$$\begin{array}{c}
&(A)& \text {When the series}\sum_ {n = 1}^{\infty} b_ {n} \text {converges, then}\sum_ {n = 1}^{\infty} a_ {n} b_ {n}\text {also converges.}\\
&(B)& \text {When the series} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n}   \text{diverges, then} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} b_{n} \text {also diverges.} \\
&(C)& \text {When the series} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|b_{n}\right|  \text {converges, then} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}^{2} b_{n}^{2}  \text {also converges.}\\
&(D)& \text {When the series} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|b_{n}\right|  \text{diverges, then}  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}^{2} b_{n}^{2} \text {also diverges.}
\end{array}$$

I know that enumerating special cases like $a_{n}=b_{n}=(-1)^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ can solve this question, but I want to know more specific mathematical proofs.

Comment: (C) is the only one that's true, so for the other three, specific counterexamples is the most appropriate way to show that they're false.

Comment: maybe you mean two sequences, instead of two series because $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are sequences